# SPARQL query: OR in FILTER?

Tags: sparql

I would like to search court cases based on their short title, but I've noticed in the RDF records that this information is sometimes stored under one property (cdm:expression_case-law_parties) and sometimes under another (cdm:expression_title_alternative). I would like to filter on both simultaneously. The below query, where I'm trying to use an OR `||` in the FILTER) does not work. What is the appropriate way?

```
PREFIX cdm: <http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#>
                            SELECT ?work ?expression ?ecli ?celex ?alttitle ?parties ?title
                            WHERE {
                            ?work a ?class.
                            ?expression cdm:expression_belongs_to_work ?work.
                                ?expression cdm:expression_title ?title.
                                ?expression cdm:expression_uses_language <http://publications.europa.eu/resource/authority/language/ENG>.
                            ?work cdm:case-law_ecli ?ecli.
                            ?work cdm:resource_legal_id_celex ?celex.
                            OPTIONAL{?expression cdm:expression_case-law_parties ?parties}
                            OPTIONAL{?expression cdm:expression_title_alternative ?alttitle}
                            FILTER(?class in (<http://publications.europa.eu/ontology/cdm#judgement>))
                            FILTER CONTAINS (?alttitle, "France v Commission") || (?parties, "France v Commission")}

LIMIT 15
```

Comment: `FILTER (CONTAINS (?alttitle, "France v Commission") || CONTAINS(?parties, "France v Commission"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Stanislav Kralin's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696670/sparql-query-or-in-filter/66709008#comment117901607_66696670):

```
FILTER (CONTAINS (?alttitle, "France v Commission") || CONTAINS(?parties, "France v Commission"))
```